# Write database table content to pdf

Tags: php

I have done a way to write the content in the db table to a pdf file.

But one field in the table contains contents with html tags.That is "< p >This is the statement< br >the next statement < /p >" like this.

I want to write this content to pdf file with html formatted. I don't want to strip tags.

The contents should in html formatted in the pdf file.

For example if table contain "< strong >" statement < /strong >" I want to write it like this in the pdf

**statement**

Is there any php function for this.

```
$pdf=new FPDF(); 
$pdf->AddPage(); //Create new PDF page 
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10); //Set the base font & size 
$pdf->Ln();//Creates a new line, blank here 
$pdf->Cell(10,5,""); 
$pdf->Cell(10,5,""); 
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12); 
$pdf->Ln(); 
$pdf->Cell(20,10,$title); 
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',6); 
$pdf->Ln(); 
$pdf->Cell(20,11, $content); 
$pdf->Ln(); 
$pdf->Ln(); 
$pdf->Cell(1150,130,"Date:".date('d-m-y')); 
$separator = md5(time()); 
$file_name='Certificate'.$type_id.'.pdf'; 
// carriage return type (we use a PHP end of line constant) 
$eol = PHP_EOL; 
$pdf->Output($file_name,'D');
```

Comment: while i am write the content to pdf the contents show along with the html tags

Comment: check the open tag function in following http://www.fpdf.de/downloads/addons/50/